# Create a class that extends and creates an element in the DOM

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, vite

**Here is my example code:**

```
class Example extends HTMLElement{
    constructor(tag:string) {
        super(document.createElement(tag)) // error
        this.innerHTML = "Hello World"
    }
}
```

Of course i get an error when i run the **super()** constructor, but how would i go about doing something like this. I want a class that can create and extend an **element/node** in the dom based on the tag named provided in the constructor . And i want to be able to access all its methods and properties in the class.

I am using vite as my bundler if that changes anything.

Comment: Can u also share the HTMLElement class code

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The HTMLElement is a built in class. And the error is just that HTMLElement dont have a constructor to call with given arguments.

Answer (score 1):

With custom elements, you are not supposed to directly call the class constructor, so you can't pass arguments. Instead, you should call `customElements.define` to get your class to handle a specific tag name. You can use element attributes to modify the behavior of the element.

```js
class ExampleTag extends HTMLElement{
    constructor() {
        super();
        const tag = this.getAttribute("tag");
        const elem = document.createElement(tag);
        elem.innerHTML = "Hello World";
        this.appendChild(elem);
    }
}
customElements.define('example-tag', ExampleTag);
```

```html
<example-tag tag="p"></example-tag>
```

Comment: but does not answer question by my understanding. I'm not trying to create a custom element, I'm simply trying to create a new dom node with tag x with createElement.  So, for the example, the html would be <p>Hello world</p>. Is there any way to just apply the created node/htmlElement to the class. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @HåkonKleven I'm not sure what you mean. You don't need a class to wrap `document.createElement('some-element')`. And if you just want a wrapper around some element, you don't need to extend `HTMLElement`.

Comment: I sorry if i wast clear but i just want to create an element based on an input tag and then and than be able to create custom properties on that element. Thats why i want to create a class wrapper so i can define custom methods on the html element in a clean way. @Unmitigated

Comment: @HåkonKleven In that case, I would suggest just creating a regular class that does *not* extend `HTMLElement`.